# How can I allow a local Dockerfile to use an .ssh key with either an id_rsa or id_ed25519 filename during build?

Tags: docker, shell, github, dockerfile

I'm extending a Dockerfile that uses the following syntax to copy a local SSH key into the container and use it during the build to pull a git repo:

```
RUN echo "${MY_GIT_SSH_KEY}" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN echo ls /root/.ssh/
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/*
RUN ssh-keyscan github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
```

This works, fine, but now Github recommends you generate a key using the

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

Which generates a file named `id_ed25519` instead of `id_rsa`.

I'm trying to modify the Dockerfile so it would allow either name locally, something like this:

```
RUN echo "${MY_GIT_SSH_KEY}" > /root/.ssh/"$(basename "$MY_GIT_SSH_KEY")"
```

But somehow I'm getting the quoting and command substitution wrong, and have tried several different variations of this command.  Can someone help me get it right?

Comment: **DO NOT PUT YOUR SSH PRIVATE KEY INTO A DOCKERFILE.**  Anyone who gets the image can trivially extract it (`docker run --rm the-image cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa`).  Consider whether your existing ssh key pair has been compromised this way and if you need to remove it from your GitHub account.

Comment: Thanks, this is happening for local builds only, and is happening as a part of a multistage build, which I believe is still considered safe.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked:

```
RUN git_basename="$(basename -- "$MY_GIT_SSH_KEY")"; echo "${MY_GIT_SSH_KEY}" > /root/.ssh/${git_basename}
```